# MySQL Returning Value that Should Be Null

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query that will look to last week and select a value and give me the count that it was used... pretty simple concept except that when I run the query I get a result and the system wasn't in use last week!

```
SELECT re.topic, COUNT(*) AS TimesUsed 
FROM ost_ticket AS us
  JOIN ost_help_topic AS re ON re.topic_id = us.topic_id
WHERE re.created  >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+7) DAY
  AND re.created  <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY
GROUP BY us.topic_id  ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC LIMIT 1
```

I can confirm that there are no tickets from last week as when I run a query to see if anything was created last week the answer is null.

```
SELECT number
FROM ost_ticket
WHERE created  >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+7) DAY
  AND created  <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY;
```

So my question essentially is am I doing something wrong with the date selection to get last weeks dates?

Comment: in the first query you check the created date in table "re", in the second you're checking the created date in table "ost_ticket"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Select from the select statement to get the column that I needed with a date since the previous Monday.

```
SELECT 
    t1.topic
FROM
    (SELECT 
        re.topic AS topic, COUNT(*) AS TimesUsed
    FROM
        ost_ticket AS us
    JOIN ost_help_topic AS re ON re.topic_id = us.topic_id
    WHERE
        re.created BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - 4) % 7) DAY), INTERVAL 4 DAY)) AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - 4) % 7) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
    GROUP BY us.topic_id
    ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC
    LIMIT 1) t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `intervals` and date values. If you want to check whether the system was in use last week, just subtract a 7 day interval from `curdate()`:

```
SELECT re.topic, COUNT(*) AS TimesUsed 
FROM ost_ticket AS us
  JOIN ost_help_topic AS re ON re.topic_id = us.topic_id
WHERE re.created  >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY -- Here!
  AND re.created  <= CURDATE() -- And here
GROUP BY us.topic_id  ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think "last week" is supposed to mean "between the two previous mondays" or something like that given the date calcs.

Comment: Yes, between the previous Mondays is my goal.